# Бесконечный цикл в QThread

Tags: c++, qt, сигналы-слоты, qthread

Итак, программа работает с джойстиком, данные с которого выводятся в интерфейс и передаются по Modbus. Для этого получение и обработку данных с джойстика было решено закинуть в отдельный поток. Был оформлен отдельный класс в `joyhid.h`:

```
#ifndef JOYHID_H
#define JOYHID_H

#include <QObject>
#include <cstdint>
#include "hidapi.h"

typedef struct _HID_JOYSTK_Info
{
    uint16_t              X;
    uint16_t              Y;
    uint16_t              Z;
    uint16_t              X_low;
    uint16_t              Y_low;
    uint8_t               buttons[5];
}
HID_JOYSTK_Info_TypeDef;

class JoyHID : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit JoyHID(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void joySlot();

signals:
    void joySignal(HID_JOYSTK_Info_TypeDef *obj);

private:
    void joyHIDUpdate(HID_JOYSTK_Info_TypeDef *obj);
};

#endif // JOYHID_H
```

В `mainwindow.cpp` закидывается в отдельный поток:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QThread *joy_thread = new QThread;
    JoyHID *joystck = new JoyHID;
    joystck->moveToThread(joy_thread);
    connect(joy_thread, SIGNAL(started()), joystck, SLOT(joySlot()));
    connect(joystck, &JoyHID::joySignal, this, &MainWindow::uiSlot);
    joy_thread->start();
}
```

В `joyhid.cpp` слот `joySlot()` выполняет вот такой незамысловатый код:

```
void JoyHID::joySlot()
{
    joyHIDUpdate(&joyInfo);
    emit joySignal(&joyInfo);
}
```

Отрабатывается одна итерация и я получаю единоразовое обновление значений. Но мне необходимо, чтобы поток крутился постоянно, обновляя значения с джоя. Первой идеей было засунуть в слот `joySlot()`, например, `while(true)`, но идея потерпела крах. Приложение висло наглухо. Собственно, вопрос, какие работоспособные альтернативы моего решения существуют и что лучше применить в данном случае?

Comment: Не должно оно виснуть - это ж отдельный поток. Ну попробуйте в конце каждого цикла делать паузу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Бесконечный цикл while(true) блокирует эвентлуп потока и события/сигналы перестают обрабатываться. Самый простой способ - инициировать обработку событий в вашем цикле:

```
void JoyHID::joySlot()
{
    while(true){
        joyHIDUpdate(&joyInfo);
        emit joySignal(&joyInfo);
        qApp->processEvents();
    };
}
```

или излучить в конце слота повторно сигнал (он встанет в очередь обработки и обработается после всего остального)

joihid.h

```
class JoyHID : public QObject
{
//.....
signals:
    void joySignal(HID_JOYSTK_Info_TypeDef *obj);
    void joyWork();
//.....
}
```

joihid.cpp

```
JoyHID::JoyHID(QObject *parent)
{
    //.....
    connect(this, &JoyHID::joyWork, this, &JoyHID::joySlot);
}

void JoyHID::joySlot()
{
    joyHIDUpdate(&joyInfo);
    emit joySignal(&joyInfo);
    emit joyWork();
}
```

А еще лучше ваш класс представить в виде машины с конечными состояниями (см [QStateMachine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstatemachine.html)). Это будет наиболее красиво и правильно

Comment: У меня есть вопрос по поводу самого простого способа, возникает интересная ситуация: при запуске приложения на форме вместо нужных значений вижу лишь одно, которое не может быть значением джойстика в данный момент и ничего более не происходит, обновления нет. При этом, стоит мне запустить дебаг с точкой в моменте обновления поля, то в значениях переменных я вижу нужные мне цифры, стоит двинуть джой и нажать "продолжить" в отладчике, как цифры изменятся в соответствии с установленным положением, почему так может происходить?

Comment: Особенности обработки эвентлупа... можете поэкспериментировать с режимами соединения сигналов/слотов (DirectConnection/QueuedConnection), но это по прежнему останется костылями. Попробуйте все же реализовать qstatemachine - это будет архитектурно правильно, красиво и легко отлаживаемо. Уверяю что разобравшись, вы все проекты в будущем будете стараться реализовывать как машины с конечными состояниями

Answer (score 2):

Как альтернативный вариант могу предложить использовать таймер, чтобы сигнал с состоянием джойстика испускался раз в заданный интервал времени. В конструкторе вашего `JoyHID` примерно так:

```
timer = new QTimer(this);
timer->setInterval(10); // will emit 100 times per second
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &JoyHID::joySlot);
timer->start();
```

Кстати при таком подходе если метод joySlot нужен только для обслуживания испускания сигнала, его можно заменить на лямбду:

```
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this]() {
    joyHIDUpdate(&joyInfo);
    emit joySignal(&joyInfo);
});
```